# Login through spring-security from javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-security

We are working on application, where my friend is working on server side (spring) and he created REST api, and I'm creating client with angularJS. REST and client webpage are on different domains, so I had to faced `Same-origin policy` - I handled this with php proxy and everything works fine. Until yesterday - now we had authentication service (spring-security) and I have no idea how to login into REST. I can login when I simple write service adress into browser, but I cant get response I need when calling from JS.

When I'm sending simple `get` request, in response I'm getting HTML code with login page. I putted `<form>` to login on my page (taken from response, so it's exacly the same as on '/login' page, I just added full action adress), but after send data I'm getting error page with this message:

```
HTTP Status 403 - Invalid CSRF Token 'blah-blah-many-numbers-and-letters' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.
```

I'm not changing this CSRF token, so perhaps I don't know the proper way to handle this (now it's sending as paramaeter in `POST` from form - `_csrf` is hidden input with `value` attribute given by server).

So after this too long introduction, my question is: how to login into REST service (through spring-security) from angularJS controller? What is wrong in my way of doing this? (something has to be wrong, because it's not working ;)).

(Sorry for my english mistakes, I'm affraid there are many of them)

Answer (score 0):

Angular have built-in support for CSRF but it use another name for CSRF Token.

If you already have CSRF Token repository in spring webservice, what have you to do is to change CSRF Token header name to `XSRF-TOKEN`.

You will find whole instruction how to solve your problem on https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii.

Comment: Thank you - I will check it and I let you know if this is it ;)

Comment: I haven't tried yet, I found other problems - token should be matched with session ID, but I didn't create session and ignore set-cookie header from response. First I have to handle that. Sorry for no response

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stateless authentication using server signed token i.e.JSON web token(JWT) for securing REST API's and using angularjs for client side implementation.

Please find the below link as reference for implementing the same:
http://blog.jdriven.com/2014/10/stateless-spring-security-part-1-stateless-csrf-protection/

Github:https://github.com/Robbert1/boot-stateless-auth

You need to have custom implementation of class AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter to avoid html response when you login into the Rest API.The blog and github reference will guide you in implementating the same.